# SQL - Summing/counting rows based on matching columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the 2 following tables

**Tracking**

```
tracking_id  item_extension  quantity
a            144             100
b            144             200
c            250             150
```

**Account**

```
tracking_id  account
a            999
b            999
c            999
```

Here's my query -

```
SELECT sum(qty) as qty, count(item_extension) as total, t.tracking_id, item_extension, account
FROM Tracking t
INNER JOIN Account a ON t.tracking_id = a.tracking_id
GROUP BY t.tracking_id, item_extension, account
```

What I want to happen here is get **count of item_extension** and **sum of quantity** based on matching **account/item_extension fields**.  So because there are 2 rows with matching account and item_extension fields, it should sum up 2 of them like so:

```
qty  total  tracking_id  item_extension  account
300  2      a            144             999
300  2      b            144             999
150  1      c            250             999
```

Instead I get this result:

```
qty  total  tracking_id  item_extension  account
100  1      a            144             999
200  1      b            144             999
150  1      c            250             999
```

Is there a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to count `item_extension` values that are not in the current row.  So, use window functions.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT sum(qty) as qty,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by item_extension) as total,
       t.tracking_id, item_extension, account
FROM Tracking t
INNER JOIN Account a ON t.tracking_id = a.tracking_id
GROUP BY t.tracking_id, item_extension, account;
```